# Redirect feed to 404 page

Tags: redirect, feed, 404-error

I would like to redirect my visitors to my 404 when they visit any feed of my page. Something like this. I would liek to do this without changing the header URL.

```
function fb_disable_feed() {

// set_404();

}
add_action('do_feed', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rdf', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_rss2', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
add_action('do_feed_atom', 'fb_disable_feed', 1);
```

Please help!

Answer (score 5):

There are three simple steps to get what you want:

1. Hook into `'template_redirect'` to act before the feed is displayed.
2. If it is a feed send a 404 status header and
3. load the 404 template.

Here is a simple plugin that does it:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: T5 404 Feed
 * Description: Sends a 404 status code for all feeds and loads the <code>404.php</code> template.
 */

add_action( 'template_redirect', 't5_404_feed', 1 );
function t5_404_feed()
{
    if ( is_feed() )
    {
        status_header( '404' );
        locate_template( array ( '404.php', 'index.php ' ), TRUE, TRUE );
        exit;
    }
}
```

I am not so sure that `404` is the proper status code. `410` (Gone) may fit better.